# Angular Forms dynamically get input values

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get values of a non-defined number of input fields in Angular?

I am using the following code to create the input fields:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" #custom="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="let elem of arr">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I get the Input of all input fields and place them into an array?

Comment: Don't use template driven forms, use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: arrays are more easily handled with reactive form, where there is `FormArray`. Consider using reactive forms.

Comment: Use a FormArray and loop on its `controls` property. Then you have all the work done for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use ngModel, consider adding a property like "position" to arr object that can be the index or what you think about. Then in the template call:

```
 <div *ngFor="let elem of arr">
```

And the ngModel:

```
[(ngModel)]="elem[elem.position]"
```